# VBA - Autofilter then copy the visible result into the newsheet

Tags: vba

This is my issue from the previous post. I'm trying to do the filter then copy the visible data into the newsheet , i write the code as below :

```
Option Explicit
Sub filter()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim item
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim mycoll As Collection
    Set mycoll = New Collection
    Set sh1 = wb.Sheets(1)
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = wb.Sheets(1).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = sh1.Range("E5:E" & lrow)
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each c In rng
        mycoll.Add c.Value, c.Value
    Next c
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set rng = sh1.Range("B4:F" & lrow)
    With rng
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add
        .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=sh1.Range("I1"), Criteria2:=sh1.Range("I2"), Operator:=xlOr
        .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=sh1.Range("K1"), Criteria2:=sh1.Range("K2"), Operator:=xlOr
        .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=sh1.Range("M1"), Criteria2:=sh1.Range("M2"), Operator:=xlOr
         ws.Name = shName(sh1.Range("I1").Value & "-" & sh1.Range("I2").Value)
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws.Range("A1")
    End With
    
End Sub
Function shName(strName As String) As String
   Dim ws As Worksheet, arrSh, arrN, maxN As Long, k As Long, El
   
   ReDim arrSh(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 1)
   For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name = strName Then
            shName = strName & "_" & 1
            Exit Function
        End If
         If InStr(ws.Name, strName & "_") > 0 Then arrSh(k) = ws.Name: k = k + 1
   Next
   If k = 0 Then shName = strName: Exit Function 'if no such a name exists
   ReDim Preserve arrSh(k - 1)
   'determine the bigger suffix:
   For Each El In arrSh
        arrN = Split(El, "_")
        If CLng(arrN(UBound(arrN))) > maxN Then maxN = CLng(arrN(UBound(arrN)))
    Next
    shName = strName & "_" & maxN + 1
End Function
```

However, It only work correctly at the first time , Can you please help look ?

[image]

Comment: Is it creating the new sheet? What does "not working correctly" mean?

Comment: Yes, It has created the new sheet with named as my code writen for the first time, after that it just created new sheet named "-" and "-_1" as you can see in my photo attached.

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging - use Debug.Print to display values inside your shName function. It's very hard to tell what your goal is in using that function - but follow the changes to shName and strName and you'll likely find your error

Comment: Thank you all , I have found the where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the comments explain what is being done. With lRow variable it will help to check the filter was changed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Region()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ol As ListObject: Set ol = ws1.ListObjects(1)
    Dim olCol As Integer, lRow As Integer
    Dim srcRng As Range, dstRng As Range
    
    Dim arrTemp As Variant, arrWs As Variant
    Dim rngFilter As Range
    
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Filter REGION
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Find last row
    lRow = ws1.Range("I1").End(xlDown).Row
    
    ' Define filter range
    Set rngFilter = ws1.Range("I1:I" & lRow)
    
    ' Copy range to array
    arrTemp = Application.Transpose(rngFilter)
    arrWs = arrTemp ' used to create shName
    
    ' Filter column REGION
    olCol = ol.ListColumns("Region").Index
    ol.Range.AutoFilter Field:=olCol, Criteria1 _
        :=arrTemp, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Filter ISP
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Find last row
    lRow = ws1.Range("K1").End(xlDown).Row
    
    ' Define filter range
    Set rngFilter = ws1.Range("K1:K" & lRow)
    
    ' Copy range to array
    arrTemp = Application.Transpose(rngFilter)
    
    ' Filter column ISP
    olCol = ol.ListColumns("ISP").Index
    ol.Range.AutoFilter Field:=olCol, Criteria1 _
        :=arrTemp, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Filter PRODUCT
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Find last row
    lRow = ws1.Range("M1").End(xlDown).Row
    
    ' Define filter range
    Set rngFilter = ws1.Range("M1:M" & lRow)
    
    ' Copy range to array
    arrTemp = Application.Transpose(rngFilter)
    
    ' Filter column Product
    olCol = ol.ListColumns("Product").Index
    ol.Range.AutoFilter Field:=olCol, Criteria1 _
        :=arrTemp, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Select or create sheet
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim wsName As String: wsName = Join(arrWs, "-"): Debug.Print wsName
    If Not ws_Exists(wsName) Then
        ' Add sheet
        Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        
        ' Rename sheet
        ws2.Name = wsName
    Else
        Set ws2 = Sheets(wsName)
    End If
    
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Copy visible rows if any
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' check visible rows
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim olRowsVisible As Integer
    olRowsVisible = ol.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' copy only if any rows visible
    If olRowsVisible > 0 Then
        Set srcRng = ol.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Set dstRng = ws2.Range("A1"): dstRng.CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        
        srcRng.Copy dstRng
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub

Function ws_Exists(SheetName As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    If Len(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Name) > 0 Then ws_Exists = True
    
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    ws_Exists = False
End Function
```

Comment: I believe you hasn't understand my issue Bro, I got the issue with creating named for the 2nd sheets and more. It didn't get (sh1.Range("I1").Value & "-" & sh1.Range("I2").Value) to name for the new sheet creating.

Comment: I think you want to create a new sheet depending on the filter applied and name it based on the filter, and then paste the filtered data to it. But for me it's not that clear what you are trying to achieve. I updated the code I posted. If this is not, put some more details and comment the code.